# Python 3.8 - Unable to update dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I have this below dictionary that I want to update

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Principal":{
            "Federated":"arn:aws:iam::111111111111:saml-provider/Test"
         },
         "Action":"sts:AssumeRoleWithSAML",
         "Condition":{
            "StringEquals":{
               "SAML:aud":"https://signin.aws.amazon.com/saml"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Want to update it to

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Principal":{
            "Federated":[
            "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:saml-provider/Test", 
            "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:saml-provider/Test2"
            ]
         },
         "Action":"sts:AssumeRoleWithSAML",
         "Condition":{
            "StringEquals":{
               "SAML:aud":"https://signin.aws.amazon.com/saml"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

i.e. add "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:saml-provider/Test2" to "Federated" and also make it a list. Below is my code

```
    new_arn = "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:saml-provider/Test2"
    my_dict = {
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
             "Effect":"Allow",
             "Principal":{
                "Federated":[
                "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:saml-provider/Test",
                ]
             },
             "Action":"sts:AssumeRoleWithSAML",
             "Condition":{
                "StringEquals":{
                   "SAML:aud":"https://signin.aws.amazon.com/saml"
                }
             }
          }
       ]
    }
    for b in my_dict['Statement']:
        updated_arn = f"['{b['Principal']['Federated']}', {new_arn}]"
        b['Principal']['Federated']: updated_arn

    print(my_dict)
```

I am bit new to python and I am not sure what am I doing wrong the dict is not getting updated. Can someone please provide some guidance on what I may be doing wrong

Comment: this is what I have, its the entire dict

Comment: You aren't assigning a list at all, you're just assigning a string that starts and ends with square brackets, so it *looks* like a list.

Comment: `my_dict["Statement"][0]["Principal"]["Federated"] = ["value1", "value2"]`

Comment: Oh, and you aren't actually assigning anything - that colon instead of an equals sign makes it a type annotation, that doesn't have any effect.

Comment: @JohnGordon I need to preserve existing values too for "Federated" key and there can be multiple values

Comment: `:` doesn't assign the value. Use `b['Principal']['Federated'] = updated_arn`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As folks commented, you're constructing a string that looks like a list here:

```py
    for b in my_dict['Statement']:
        updated_arn = f"['{b['Principal']['Federated']}', {new_arn}]"
        b['Principal']['Federated']: updated_arn
```

You can create a real list instead:

```py
    for b in my_dict['Statement']:
        updated_arn = [b['Principal']['Federated'], new_arn]
        b['Principal']['Federated'] = updated_arn
        # note it's `=` not `:` here
```

---

*Edit:*
If `Federated` is sometimes a string, and sometimes already a list, you'll need to check its type and act accordingly:

```py
    for b in my_dict['Statement']:
        federated = b['Principal']['Federated']
        if isinstance(federated, list):
            federated.append(new_arn)
            # (which updates the list within the dict, no need to assign back to the dict)
        else:
            b['Principal']['Federated'] = [federated, new_arn]
```

Comment: no I want it in dict type

Comment: You're transforming a dict which contains a string value to a dict which contains a list value. That's what this answer does.

Comment: Thank you yes I understand now, but how to handle a case where there multiple values like TestA, TestB, TestC and Test2 has to be added

Comment: righto, I've updated my answer to show how you can check for this :)

Comment: Thank you that worked appreciate all the help

Answer (score 0):

You can append to the current value of "Federated" as follows:

```
for b in my_dict['Statement']:
       b['Principal']['Federated'].append(new_arn)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for the data given, where `b['Principal']['Federated']` is a string not a list.